# Adding new column to GeoDataFrame and it says values' length does not match index when it does

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, shapefile, geopandas

The goal is to read a shapefile, get the area of each polygon (municipalities), and add the area in a new column named 'Area'.

```
cs = gpd.read_file('munis.shp')
area_fd = []
area = cs['geometry'].map(lambda p: p.area / 10**6)
area_fd.append(area)
cs = cs.assign(Area =  area_fd) #or cs['Area'] = area_fd
```

When I run `print(cs['NAME_2'].head)` it returns the 38 munis (0-38) and `print(area_fd)` gives 38 values too. But when I run the code, it says `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`. I already looked up to similar GISSE and SO threads but no solution worked.

Comment: `area_fd.append` is weird because you're adding the series as an entry into the list so assigning it back like you do later is incorrect. What is wrong with `cs.assign(Area=area)`?

Comment: Ran the code with your solution and it worked! I was thinking I need to put the area values in a list so that it gets the right index and the values match the polygon they were calculated from. Thank you.

Comment: "_so that it gets the right index and the values match the polygon they were calculated from_" if you print `area` you will see it is a pandas series with the same index as `cs`. Doing `cs.assign(Area=area)` is exactly the way to achieve what you just said.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to directly do something like the following,

```
import geopandas as gpd

cs = gpd.read_file('munis.shp')

cs['Area'] = cs['geometry'].area / 10**6
```